# Scraping image sizes for different screen sizes

Tags: php, html, css, image, web-scraping

I'm writing a script that let's me know how many images on my website are too big for various screen sizes (eg you have a 500x500 image that may render as 100x100 on mobile). At present it works as a (temporary) JS script that I run and it AJAX's the information to the database for me to reference when optimising the images later.

My issue is this isn't very effective because the website has 100s of pages and I'd quite like to automate it rather than manually running the script on all the 100s of pages, each on various screen sizes. I did consider a script that I put a list of URLs into and it cycles through all 100 pages via form of a redirect after each script has run, but this doesn't seem very time efficient so would like to automate it in way of a server-side php script. But I can't think/don't know of a way that I can get the render size of an image (not the ***actual*** size) using a php scrape of a page.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: if the ratio is the same it kind of doesn't matter, you could use `<picture>` element or media queries to change to a more suitable image done though a resize script i.e `image.png?w=500` etc.. the real issue is serving a 25MB image when it could be optimised to a few kb's, which you can trivially see from ordering a directory by size then fixing images which are blatantly too large (and that would be easy to code vs scraping the entire site).

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted what I'm trying to do. I may have an image that is 500x500 that on desktop is rendered as 500x500, but on mobile is 100x100. At present I do not have a 100x100 version of the image, nor (without checking) know that it renders at 100x100. So I have a JS script that runs after the (mobile size) page loads to tell me that on mobile it is 100x100. I can then use this to feature in the <picture> tag you mention. What I'm hoping to do is automate it further without needing to open the page in a browser so that a server (with php) can find the various image sizes.

Comment: yeah its unclear, head over to [this script](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/lcherone/sharp-test/tree/master/?fontsize=14) and your clearly see its only the filesize which really matters if you use correct css to scale the image within the element. Be it 500x500, 250x250, 100x100 its the same ratio so does not effect what the image actually looks like. If you don't use any css then obviously a 500x image rendered on 100x device will cause issues, sounds like xy problem

Comment: also you could offload the check/task to the user and simply post up the dimensions vs scrapping the site

Comment: You can not get the actual size an image will render at, by merely scraping the HTML code of the page. The image gets displayed in a certain size, because the HTML has been parsed, and all the CSS applied (and maybe JS has manipulated the DOM as well, who knows) - PHP can’t really do that for you, not in any proper way anyway. A _headless browser_ is what you’d want if you wanted to automate such tasks, that require actual rendering of the page first of all.

Comment: Symfony has a really nice [headless browser](https://github.com/symfony/panther) that you could use to automate a lot of this, and you can then invoke your JS as needed. Also, [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test.html#Add-a-test-file) is a really great tool that is intended for testing but could be used for this, too.